# Using untrusted app as the default way to open a file

Tags: macos, bash, file-association, automator

I've turned a short shell script into an Application using Automator. The shell script converts a `.dot` file into a `.png` and opens the `.png`

Something like

```
dot -Tpng "$@" -o img.png
open img.png
```

I'm trying to set this as the default app for opening all `.dot` by right clicking a `.dot` file and choosing `open with -> other -> myApp` and checking the "*Always run with this option*".

The first time I try and open a `.dot` file I get an error saying programs from unidentified developers cannot be run. After that the 'open with' program for `.dot` files is reverted back to the default option.

I tried to disable gatekeeper in `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General` but the only options I have are to allow only App Store apps or  App Store and trusted developer apps.

Is there some way I can set my App to be the default app for openening `.dot` files without being verified?

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do?